# Visual Studio Project Looks different when built on Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, designer

When I debug my program it looks way different than the designer view. Here are some pics of the tool open next to the designer window:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/61041be81f62d1775d2f90ff97eb631f.png]

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/a130e75156b86c7f6f9ff9a27a90e600.png]

Notice how text is diffrent and buttons have a huge gap in the designer on the right side...

(And no it has nothing to do with the build being out dated from the designer or any thing like that because its never looked like this ever)

This makes tool building almost impossible...

Comment: Do you have a high-dpi screen?

Comment: IT turns out Windows 10 set my screen size to 125% and that was causing the error thanks a ton for pointing me in the right direction! Although it wasn't an issue in windows 7 :/

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 seems to have rewritten the entire designer, and it has all tons of problems when designing on high-dpi screens so no surprise it has similar problems on non-100% scale settings.